# How do I access every article on a particular day from the NY Times API?

Tags: json, api, web-scraping

I have accessed the NYT API.

I've initially used the http call:  `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?fq=source:("The New York Times")AND pub_date:("2019-04-04")&api-key=<MY KEY HERE>`.

This gets me a json with this section:

```
"meta": {
      "hits": 176,
      "offset": 0,
      "time": 8
    }
```

I then cycle through each hit or page with the following call: `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?fq=source:("The New York Times")AND pub_date:("2019-04-04") AND page=<EACH NUMBER> &api-key=<MY KEY HERE>`.

However I'm only getting maybe 70 articles when I should be getting 150+. What am I doing wrong in my call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the API call to the following this will work:

```
articlesearch.json?fq=source:"The New York Times"&sort=newest&begin_date=20190404&end_date=20190404&page=0
...
articlesearch.json?fq=source:"The New York Times"&sort=newest&begin_date=20190404&end_date=20190404&page=21
```